# Picking Phone Number from Phone CLI into ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hope all of you doing well and enjoying life.

My question is, I wanna take phone number data from a phone CLI attached to phone set into ASP.NET MVC application.i.e

I have a field of PhoneNumber where i used to insert data manually. What I want is to insert this phone number automatically from attached CLI.

Is it Possible?